# Windows cmd java output nothing

Tags: java, windows

Today the program could not run in Windows Server 2008 r2. And when I run java.exe in windows cmd, I got nothing output, just like the img, java.exe not working, javac is workding, I rename java.exe to c2.exe , then c2.exe is working.

Is there any suggestion?

[No output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klhPU.png)
[Java in path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PFjx.png)

Comment: Check your `PATH` so you know for sure which file is executed.

Comment: additionally, `where java` will tell you the locations of all the programs named `java` on your path.

Comment: check you have **java.bat** file in the path ,particularly E:\. It can be simulated if you have java.bat

Comment: I rename all of the the java.exe. At last I rename `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe` to `c3.exe`，then I can't find java in path. After that `c3.exe` is working, rename `c3.exe` to `java.exe`, it failed again.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open windows search and type in "Edit the System Environment Variables", or just "environment".
2. Under the advanced tab, click on the "Environment Variables" button.
3. In the top portion of the dialog, scroll down until you see "Path", and click on edit.
4. Look for whatever directory your java path is pointed to and click delete.
5. Click "new", then click browse, and locate the java.exe file. Make sure you don't change the original file name.
6. If this doesn't work, uninstall java and get the latest version for your system from the oracle website, and add the install location to the system path as described in the previous steps.